# Windows 10 freezes for few seconds

Tags: windows, freeze, noise

here is my issue.
I'm experiencing this issue two or three times a day.

Basically the image on the screen freezes for 4-5 seconds and the audio speed seems to "slow down" or it makes a crackling noise. This happens while doing normal stuff and it is not related to gaming (actually during gaming I never ran into this issue but this could be related to the fact that I don't play games to many hours).

This started happening during the time I installed my new GPU and my new external HDD (where my games are installed). I never ran in this issue using the integrated GPU and the main SSD drive.

I tried to uninstall all Radeon drivers and reinstall them using the AMD recommended procedure but the problem still persist.

I ran memtest86 and BurnInTest and everything is ok.

I have noticed one thing: when the first freeze occurs, I hear like a startup sound from my case.

Can it be related to the HDD go to sleep setting of windows 10?

Windows event viewer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdGYd.jpg

System configuration:

Motherboard: ASRock B360 Pro4

CPU: Intel i5 8400

Memory: Crucial Ballistix Sport 16GB DDR4

PSU: Be Quiet! Straight Power 10 500W

SSD (main drive): Samsung 850 EVO (Sata III)

HDD (second drive): Seagate 4TB

GPU: SAPPHIRE NITRO+ RX 580 Special Edition

VBIOS: 113-BE366EU-Z48

Driver: Radeon Software Version 19.1.1

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64, Verion 1803, OS build 17134.523

Monitor: Samsung C24FG73-LC24FG73FQUXEN (FreeSync enabled, using Display Port).

Comment: Oh boy there are a lot of possible causes for this. Since you don't game much, I would suggest your first step be to remove the GPU and uninstall it's drivers, if the problem persists, then upnlug the HDD. If the problem persists, plug it all back in and reinstall windows, that tends to work for problems like this (unless the hardware is faulty that is)

Comment: A few Qs that might help narrow it down...
Does your mouse cursor freeze as well?

Have you checked Windows Event Viewer to see what happens before/during/after?

You mentioned that the audio slows. Does it happen even if there is no audio playing?

Comment: @PFitz Hello, thanks for your time! Yes, the mouse cursor freezes as well. Yes the problem occurs even when no audio is playing (speakers are always connected and on). But sometimes the image freezes and the audio just stop playing, or as I said the image stops and the audio slows.
Here is a screenshot of the Event Viewer (I don't know what to search for):
https://imgur.com/jG1mMHL

Comment: What are the SMART details of the Seagate drive? Compare events in the SMART details to the power on hours and you'll likely see that drive is causing your problems.

Comment: @shawn thanks for you reply! Here is a screen of CrystalDiskInfo: 
https://imgur.com/RDkglNS

Comment: Result of SMART test using SeaTools: https://imgur.com/TAhFw0j

Comment: @Karim that doesn't actually show the SMART log. Consider [SmartMonTools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) and this syntax: `smartctl -a sdb` where sdb is the Seagate drive. If sdb doesn't work you'll need to use `smartctl --scan` to identify the drive.

Comment: @shawn Using sdb it runs on my Samsung ssd, so I used sda instead. Here is the result:
part1: https://imgur.com/5RADlYb
part2: https://imgur.com/bIe6bYA

I don't know if it is important but I have unplugged and plubbed in again the hdd before running the software.

Comment: No log included, so no indication that this is the source. Must be something else.

Comment: When you say "startup sound," do you mean beeps from the motherboard speaker? I'm wondering if they might be diagnostic codes similar to POST tones or LED blinks.

Comment: @P Fitz no no bip, it's like something that starts spinning. Maybe gpu fan or external HDD? I will try to discover the source of the sound. Any ideas of the problem if the sound comes from gpu fans or hdd?

Comment: Ok guys, I have been running the PC for some days now with the "Turn off hard disk after" option set to "Never" and freezings seem to be gone.

Comment: For more info look here:
https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=3875